# Brace expansion of {1..$n}

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, brace-expansion

I am trying to loop from 1 to n where n is from user input.
If I do:

```
read n
echo {1..$n}
```

I get this output for the input 5

```
{1..5}
```

How do I make it expand to

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: You *cannot* use variables within brace-expansion. (not without the cludge of `eval` -- don't do it, use a proper loop, or `seq` or the like) Since this is base, just use a C-style `for` loop, e.g. `for ((i = 1; i <= n; i++)); do...`

Comment: I suggest to use a function: `echo $(c 1 $n)`. `echo` can be omitted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple by trying to do it with a `for` loop as follows.

```
echo "enter number..."
read n

for((i=1;i<=n;i++)); do
        echo "$i"
done
```

Or use `seq` with `for` loop as follows too.

```
echo "Enter number:"
read howmany
for i in $(seq 1 $howmany); do
  echo "$i";
done
```

Curly braces don't support variables in bash, though `eval` could be used but ***it is evil*** and have loopholes, why so see this link carefully http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: You have a good answer, but I have more explanation in a comment -- try adding a bit of explanation so the user knows why what he is doing is wrong `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, oh sorry looks like 1 min difference only, let me add some more comments to it now too.

Comment: Good deal -- remember - you step into the role of 'teacher' when answering. We all remember to good ones, and the ones we love to hate... (you may want to even explain why the `'$'` isn't needed to dereference variables with `((...))`, just so he (or she) isn't scratching their head)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, sure, I tried to find on SO and got to know why eval is evil so added a link with a line of explanation too sir, please feel free to edit it in case you think we could add something to it too.